# Iterative Imputer giving same output value for all NaNs for a given column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I currently have a data frame with ~350 columns. I want to impute the NaNs in one of these columns using several other columns using iterative imputer and `ExtraTreesRegressor`. I've created a smaller data frame containing the features of interest. My dataframe looks like:

[image]

I want to impute NaNs in `first_seen_days` however the issue I'm having is that all NaNs are imputed using the same value. I'm expecting each NaN to be imputed with a different value. This is my code:

```
data_interpolation = df_sample[["first_seen_days","domain_relevant_info_id", 
             "reason_id", "score.1", "status_id"]]

imp = IterativeImputer(random_state = 0)

imp.fit(data_interpolation)
X = data_interpolation

data_interpolation["first_seen_days"] = imp.transform(X)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried replicating your problem. I am able to impute different values using `ExtraTreesRegressor`. Based on this, your problem could be because of inherent property of your data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor

np.random.seed(0)
X = np.random.rand(20, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
#randomly assign these indexes nan
for i in [3, 5, 7, 15]:
    df.iloc[i]["A"] = np.nan

##imputation - part of code from the question
imp = IterativeImputer(estimator=ExtraTreesRegressor(), random_state = 0)
imp.fit(df)
X = df
df["A"] = imp.transform(X)
#imputed values
print(df.iloc[[3, 5, 7, 15]]["A"])

#output
3     0.706066
5     0.561352
7     0.776586
15    0.550094
```